# int-file:outbound-gateway ignored duplicate file name in `outbound-gateway ` memory state?

Tags: spring, spring-integration

Thanks for attention, i using Spring Integration in my project, i want to retrieve files from servers into tmp folder by `int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter`and move files to orginal forder by `int-file:outbound-gateway` for future batch processing, but i feel when file name is duplicate `int-file:outbound-gateway` not working for me and does not transmit the file and seems ignore them, how to solving this my problem.

```
<int-file:outbound-gateway id="tmp-mover"
                               request-channel="ready-to-process-inbound-tmp-mover"
                               reply-channel="ready-to-process-inbound"
                               directory="${backupRootPath}/ali/in//"
                               mode="REPLACE" delete-source-files="true"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `local-filter` in the ftp inbound channel adapter to an `AcceptAllFileListFilter`. By default, it's an `AcceptOnceFileListFilter`.